# How to get all openldap users?

Tags: openldap

how to can i get all users list on edirectory (or openldap) on opensuse?
or make a full backup from openldap database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for every uid in your ldap server with ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=*
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a full backup of your OpenLDAP server is a different thing than getting a user list.

A backup is best made on the server itself using the `slapcat` utility. `slapcat` directly reads the backend database files. This way it can make a real full backup fast, including operational attributes which are normally hidden.

However, directly opening the database files also means it can only work on the server where the OpenLDAP daemon (`slapd`) is located, and `slapcat` needs to run as root.

The OpenLDAP daemon `slapd` does not need to run for `slapcat` to work, but it is OK if it does.

This simple command is often enough to dump a full backup to an LDIF file.

```
slapcat >/your/backup/file.ldif
```

But refer to the man page for details if you also want to backup the `cn=config` database or your setup has more than one LDAP database.

The resulting LDIF file could be used to `grep` for your user list by the way.